# Symfony does not find routes in Controller

Tags: php, symfony

I recently got a new laptop, and after I installed PHP 8.2.8 and Symfony, I thought I'd be able to start a new Symfony 5.4 webapp project but whenever I start the local server it doesn't find the routes in my Controller.

I used the command `php bin/console make:controller` which has done the trick previously, but now doesn't seem to get it to work.

I've tried looking for answers online but there's no one who has had the same problem, as far as I know. I get the `No route found for "GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/index"` error while the following code is in my IndexController:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/index', name: 'app_index')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'IndexController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Just the template, as you can see.

```
-------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
  Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
  _preview_error             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
  _wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
  _profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/
  _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search
  _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar
  _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
  _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
  _profiler_open_file        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open
  _profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}
  _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router
  _profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception
  _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
```

These are the routes.

I feel like something might've gone wrong during the installation of Symfony, but I have no clue what's gone wrong.

Comment: Do you have `type: attribute` for your controller config? https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-attributes

Comment: If you have no routes configured do you at least get the the Symfony welcome page? Maybe try http://localhost:8000/index, it'd be odd if that worked but stranger things have happened.

Comment: Are you sure you started the server in your project's main directory?  You are using `symfony server:start`?  Any errors when the server starts?  How did you create you app in the first place? Something like `symfony new --full --version=lts`?  It is very puzzling that your route is not showing up using the out of the box setup.  Did you mess around with `src/Kernel.php` at all?

Comment: check if you haves two routes with the same name

Comment: @MohammedAbdelouahab Two routes with the same name just results in one route overriding the other.  The route name would still show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was an idiot, and forgot to require annotations in Symfony.
Thanks for the help, but after months of setting up Symfony for the first time i completely forgot the most basic step: requiring annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to execute `bin/console cache:clear` after every configuration change

Comment: If you need to do this in development mode than you have something seriously wrong with your configuration setup.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up router to parse attributes on files in the Controller directory. Paste this code to your `config/routes/attributes.yaml`:

```yaml
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute
```

Comment: There was no such file so I created it, though it didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @mauritsf In 5.4 you probably have a file `config/routes/annotations.yaml`.  If such a file exist then check to see if type is set to attribute.  It might still be at annotation.